# PostgreSQL : How to run ALTER queries returned as a result from SQL SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, ddl

I want to add a new column to all tables with table name pattern **table_**<>**_details**.

I use this query :

```
 select 'alter table ' || table_name || ' ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;'
 from information_schema.tables
 where table_name like 'table_%_details';
```

to generate the DDL queries which looks like :

```
alter table table_1_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
alter table table_2_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
alter table table_3_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
alter table table_4_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
alter table table_5_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
alter table table_6_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
alter table table_7_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;
```

I tried to loop through these records using the following script :

```
do $$ declare c_query cursor for
select
    'alter table ' || table_name || ' ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;'
from
    information_schema.tables
where
    table_name like 'table_%_details';

begin
 for rec in c_query loop
 execute rec;
end loop;

close c_query;
end $$
```

I have tried to fine tune this script but with no success, I'm getting the following error:

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ""alter table table_1_details ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;""
  Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at EXECUTE statement
```

my question is how to modify this scrip to loop through all these results and apply the DDL to database , note (I do not want to create functions).

please any Ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just loop over the resultset of `infomation_schema.tables` and then use `EXECUTE` with your concatenated `ALTER TABLE` statements

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
             WHERE table_name LIKE 'table_%_details' LOOP
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || row.table_name || ' ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;';
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

**EDIT**: Alternatively you can use `FORMAT` to concatenate your strings instead of using `||`, as pointed out by @a_horse_with_no_name

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;',row.table_name);
```

Check this [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a1567ec96253fd6179f3cf08dfd26ee9)

Comment: Even better: `execute format('ALTER TABLE %I ADD COLUMN CREATED TIMESTAMP;', row.table_name);`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the hint, it indeed looks neater! I will add it to the answer :)

Comment: works like a charm .

thanks a lot JimJones you saved my time , also thanks @a_horse_with_no_name for your hint as  it looks neater!.